# OneDrive Picker not loading

Tags: onedrive

The OneDriver Picker does not load after the authentication process but instead shows a spinner.

**Steps to Reproduce**

OneDrive Scripts Tested:

- https://js.live.net/v7.2/OneDrive.debug.js
- https://js.live.net/v7.2/OneDrive.js

Code used to Initiate the OneDriver Picker:

```
function launchOneDriverPicker() {
      debugger;
      var odOptions = {
        clientId: "${clientId}",
        action: "share",
        multiSelect: true,
        openInNewWindow: true,
        advanced: {
          redirectUri: "${redirectUri}"
        },
        success: function(r) {
        },
        cancel: function() {
        },
        error: function(error) {
        }
      };
      OneDrive.open(odOptions);
    }
```

Environments Tested:
- Chrome (Normal/Incognito)
- Firefox (Normal/Incognito)

**Steps**

- The page hosting the OneDrive Picker and redirect URLs are served from the same domain
- The redirect occurs to a redirect page with the following content hosted under the same domain (domain/redirect):

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v7.2/OneDrive.debug.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

**Additional Notes**

- The above setup  works correctly with the OneDriver Picker 7.0 as noted in an earlier issue:
  https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/824
- While debugging the issue I noticed that the OneDriver Picker makes a cross document call to the parent window which opened the Picker. There are no errors up to this point but the parent page does not receive this message.
- The domain specified in the cross document call is correct

**Reference**

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/js-v72/open-file?view=odsp-graph-online#using-a-custom-redirect-uri